# sphinx search math operation between fields

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

Since I'm moving to sphinx search engine to improove my ebsite performance I'm trying to translate the old mysql queries to new sphinx language.

The point is to sort results based on a math operation between votes to my posts and the points given for each vote (going from 1 to 5).

So for example, if i got 3 votes for a post and I got vote 1=5points vote 2=3points and vote 3=2points, my table will contain a field named votes with an integer = 3 (votes=3) and a field with an integer of 5+3+2 (points=10).

Due to this the final rating for such post will be points/votes, in this example it will be 10/3=3,333...

Assuming I'm using the sphinx api to get a list of top rated posts in DESCENDING order, this is the old mysql query i had on my php script:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY points/votes DESC LIMIT $start,$stop");
```

I tried to build a sphinx query, but it is not working and always giving 0 results. Please read tall the // commented lines that describe all the tries I did.

```
require("sphinxapi.php");
$cl = new SphinxClient;
$index = index;
$cl->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN);
//$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'IDIV(points,votes) DESC'); //not working
//$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '(points DIV votes) DESC'); //not working
//$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'points/votes DESC'); //not working
//$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '(points/votes) DESC'); //not working
$cl->setLimits($start,$stop,$max_matches=1000);
$query = "";
```

Would you please help me out finding what's wrong... thanks.

Comment: you need to use `SPH_SORT_EXPR` to use arithmetic expressions

Comment: I already tried SPH_SORT_EXPR and I got zero results indeed

Comment: it doesn't affect your selection how does a sort give you 0 results?

Comment: Actually I think there's smoething wrong in my sphinx configuration.

Is is possible to perform arithmetical operations on a sql_field_string in sphinx?

Because If i do SPH_SORT_EXPR on the document $id or on @weight is usually works but when I try to do any math operation on any other field (usually bigint fields) it gives 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `SPH_SORT_EXPR`

```
$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXPR, '(points/votes) DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need points and votes to be `Attributes`, NOT `fields`. Attributes are stored in the index, can be used for sorting etc. Arithmetic can only be performed on numeric attributes (not strings)

The correct syntax for `SPH_SORT_EXPR` (assuming you've already got the attributes) would be

```
$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXPR, 'points/votes');
```

SPH_SORT_EXPR is ALWAYS descending, so you dont need it DESC on the end.

But rather than have sphinx calculate that ratio every single time, you would porbbaly be better calculating during `sql_query` and storing it as single number attribute. TIP: store as an integer, not float. Integers are more efficient to sort by.